# jQuery select change value in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to simply change the value of a hidden form input when the roll list changes.

**HTML**

```
<input id="foo" name="foo" type="hidden" />

<select id="logo" name="logo">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#logo").on('change', function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $("#foo").val(x);
});
});
```

This doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: what errors you get when you say `This doesn't work.`?

Comment: Works for me with this exact code... http://jsfiddle.net/nKtrQ/

Comment: Works fine with this code... can't see the problem...

Comment: I'm terribly sorry.. It did work. I made a typo in dreamweaver.. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

This code works:

http://jsfiddle.net/Recode/D8nHw/

```
<input id="foo" name="foo" type="text" />
```

I only changed input to text so it is visible.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: This was close, but you can set the value attribute of the hidden input like this `$("#foo").attr("value", x)` updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D8nHw/1/

Comment: @PaulAldred-Bann Why they use $("#foo").attr("value", x) already it works fine.